# User Interface Design TableView Like

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, tableview, uitableview

I am recently working on this project as below.

[image]

I am thinking to use TableView or use UIButton/UILabel or some other UI elements to create the interface shown above. Does anyone can give me some suggestions about which way would be the best approach, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has a `UINavigationController`

`UINavigationController.view` has a `UITableView`

`UITableViews` cell is a `CustomCell`

The `CustomCell` you can add `backgroundImage` or add some subviews

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through customizing UITableView Cell.

You can find a good [video tutorial](http://vivianaranha.com/iphoneipad-tutorial-lesson-15-custom-uitableviewcell/) here

Comment: But, using UITableView will have a line between each cell.

Comment: Apply this property [self.myTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];